# Symfony2 + Doctrine - Filtering

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-optimization, dql

I've got a `OneToMany` relationship where one football team has many players. I want to list all football teams and display the name of the captain for each team.

Each player entity has a foreign key (team_id) and a field 'captain' which is set to 0 or 1. I'm currently running the following query:

```
 $teams = $this
             ->getDoctrine()
             ->getRepository('FootballWebsiteBundle:Team')
              ->createQueryBuilder('t')
             ->setFirstResult(($pageNumber * $resultPerPage) - $resultPerPage)
             ->setMaxResults($resultPerPage)
             ->add('where','t.deleted = 0')
             ->add('orderBy', 't.name DESC')
             ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Then when I loop through each team in twig I run team.getTeamCaptain().getName() which is a filter within my Team entity:

```
public function getTeamCaptain() {
    $them  = $this->players->filter(function($p) {
        return $p->getCaptain() == 1;
    });

    return $them->first();
}
```

Is there a better way to run this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you may want to [fetch-join](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) the players of each retrieved team to avoid having them lazy loaded during rendering of the template. Here's the DQL:

```
SELECT
    t, p
FROM
    FootballWebsiteBundle:Team t
LEFT JOIN
    t.players p
WHERE
    t.deleted = 0
ORDER BY
    t.name DESC
```

Which can be built with following query builder API calls:

```
 $teamsQuery = $this
         ->getDoctrine()
         ->getRepository('FootballWebsiteBundle:Team')
         ->createQueryBuilder('t')
         ->addSelect('p')
         ->leftJoin('t.players', 'p')
         ->add('where','t.deleted = 0')
         ->add('orderBy', 't.name DESC')
         ->getQuery()
```

Then you wrap this query into a [`Paginator`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html) object (since `setMaxResults` and `setFirstResult` [cannot be trusted when fetch-joining](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only)):

```
$paginator = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($teamsQuery, true);

$teamsQuery
     ->setFirstResult(($pageNumber * $resultPerPage) - $resultPerPage)
     ->setMaxResults($resultPerPage)
```

In your view you can then iterate on the teams like following pseudo-code:

```
foreach ($paginator as $team) {
    echo $team->getTeamCaptain() . "\n";
}
```

You can also gain some extra performance in your `getTeamCaptain` method by using the [`Selectable` API](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections):

```
public function getTeamCaptain() {
    $criteria = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria();

    $criteria->andWhere($criteria->expr()->eq('captain', 1));

    return $this->players->matching($criteria)->first();
}
```

The advantage here is mainly relevant when the association `players` is not yet initialized, since this will avoid loading it entirely. This is not the case, but I consider it a good practice (instead of re-inventing collection filtering logic).

Comment: To anyone who is mystified by this answer:  The last block answers the specific   question posed, and the rest talks about improving a situation which needed to be improved but was not actually asked about.

Comment: @Lighthart: no, the user asked for a way of optimizing the logic. His initial version produced `N*M+1` queries because of lazy initialization of the `Team#players` collection and then of the single players in those collections to check if `player.captain == 1`. Optimizing only `getTeamCaptain` would still cause `N+1` queries to initialize the collections. Fetch-joining the `Team#players` collection reduces all this logic to `1` single query.

So optimizing only `getTeamCaptain` here would by far not be enough.

Comment: The paginator has nothing to do with that.

Comment: As I've stated above, without a paginator there, you'd have weird results (not corresponding to the set `setMaxResults` and `setFirstResult`) because of the fetch-join. If you want to iterate over the results, you will need to use the paginator API. If you use this stuff in business logic without being aware of the consequences, then this can be very dangerous.

Comment: @Lighthart you can read more about that in paragraph http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only

Comment: I get the error - Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry::createQueryBuilder()

Comment: @user1961082 you have to call `createQueryBuilder` on an instance of `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager`.

Comment: The error goes if I use $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FootballWebsiteBundle:Team')->createQueryBuilder('t') but then does this work with `->select('t', 'p')
         ->from('FootballWebsiteBundle:Team', 't')
         ->createQueryBuilder('t')` because we are using createQueryBuilder twice then?!

Comment: @ocramius: Illuminating.  I need to investigate why I've never had this problem.

Comment: Can you please update your query using $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FootballWebsiteBundle:Team')->createQueryBu‌​ilder('t')?

Comment: Thanks @Ocramius that's perfect! Each team can also have many other teams (reserves, youth teams etc) and are identified using a foreign key (parent_team_id). Is it possible within the above query to add a sub query to count all other teams i.e `SELECT COUNT(ct.id) FROM team ct WHERE ct.parent_team_id = t.id`

Comment: Also, can I specify certain fields that I want to select from team and players so that Im not selecting all fields?

Comment: @user1961082 nothing forbids that, but I don't see real use in that if you're not building a giant website with bajillions requests per second.

Comment: So would it be `->createQueryBuilder('p.id', 'p.name')` etc or would you have to use addselect? What about the count sub query? This is so that when I list all teams I can print the number of related teams for each. Can you please add these to your example too?

Comment: The count subqueries are done by the paginator itself. I would simply call `$qb->select('p.id', 'p.name')` to replace the existing selected fields.

If you want to count all the teams, simply use `count($paginator)`.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood, I am counting related teams. So each team entity has a `parent_team_id` which links it to another team. I.e an under 21 team may have a parent_team_id of 1 which will relate to the team entity with id 1. Another team e.g reserve team could also have parent_team_id of 1 so when I loop through all teams, team with id 1 will have a count of 2 because it has 2 related teams.

Comment: @user1961082 that's another question. Please don't use this comment thread to solve another problem